# Should the LEGO Batcave step 264 use 1x1 Technic bricks?

Tags: piece-information, sets, instructions

I've been building the [Batcave – Shadow Box (76252)](https://brickset.com/sets/76252-1/Batcave-%E2%80%93-Shadow-Box):

[image: Box photo]

I have gotten to step 264 and it seems odd to me that the single back bricks have a hole in them as they seem to go in sideways in the picture blocking the holes - hence only a single solid brick was really needed?

Answer (score 20):

This is likely correct. Here's the instruction step that you mentioned:

[image: Step 264]

In order to keep costs lower, TLG tries to limit the number of unique elements in a set and in an individual bag within a set.

The part you mentioned could have been a 1x1 system brick, but using a Technic brick here also works fine. Bag 9, the bag used for this step, already includes 1x1 Technic bricks as they are needed for subsequent steps, such as 265:

[image: Step 265]

None of the other steps related to bag 9 use a 1x1 System brick. It is likely that the 1x1 Technic brick was used in step 264 in order to avoid having to include another element in this bag.

Comment: As well as keeping costs low, it also reduces the risk of using the wrong part by mistake, leading to much frustration later in the build

Comment: @MatthewJensen UGH, you just gave me flashbacks to building the Colosseum.  I think I averaged 2 wrong bricks or plates per 3 segments of the build.